# Mysql Count ignores the order by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to have a `count(t.name)` in my query to count the number of rows, however once I add the `count(t.name)` the `order by` gets ignored - I still get the results and the correct number of rows but in the wrong order.

```
SELECT t.name, t.team_id, count(t.name) as count
               FROM st_team t INNER JOIN st_position p
               ON t.team_id = p.team_id
               WHERE p.league_id = '$league_id'
               AND p.type = 'full'
               AND p.grid = '0'
               ORDER BY t.name
               LIMIT 0,1
```

I'm thinking it must have something to do with the 't.' prefix but trying various combinations hasnt got me anywhere.

Any help much appreciated, cheers P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need the Count , you need to have Group by:

```
           AND p.grid = '0'
           GROUP BY t.name
           ORDER BY t.name
           LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a summary function (`COUNT`), you need a `GROUP BY` statement in your query.

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    t.team_id,
    COUNT(t.name) as count
FROM
    st_team t
        INNER JOIN
    st_position p USING(team_id)
WHERE
    p.league_id = '$league_id'
    AND p.type = 'full'
    AND p.grid = '0'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1  --This orders by t.name in ascending order. Change to 3 DESC to order by count descending
LIMIT 0,1;
```